# The background-image doesn't work on the seamless checkout of Bigcartel

Tags: css, bigcartel

I have a problem with the background when I choose to display seamless checkout on my bigcartel shop.

The .css stylesheet writes a `background-color`, but goes to find my `background-image`, and nothing works! Instead the background is white, and nobody can read anything because all of my elements are white...

If I want that customers see something I have to disable my background image and set a primary color.

I'm French so excuse my english!

Comment: Can you show me the responsible css code? :)

Comment: Can you provide your code into a JSFiddle too ? (hello fellow french !)

Comment: Hello !
I don't have any access to the css code... It's the problem !! ;-(